# HTML blank screen

Tags: javascript, html

Why does this result in a blank screen?

**01_using_javascript.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title> Test </title>
      <script src="01_using_javascript.js"> </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p id="demo"></p>
    </body>
  </html>
```

**01_using_javascript.js**:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Hi;
```

Comment: check the developer tools console for error messages regarding `undefined` not having a property called `innerHTML` - the **developer** tools console (usually F12 on the keyboard) should be your first debugging avenue

Comment: Put "Hi" in quotes; as is your script is treating `Hi` as an (empty) variable.

Comment: @JaromandaX F12 gives me Inspect Element (I am using Google Chrome).

Comment: When on the Inspect Element window, you can press `ESC` to open a quick console. Or just click on the `Console` tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not only do you have to wrap `Hi` with quotes but you also need to wait for the DOM to load the elements you want to modify. Either you put the `script` tag after the `p` element, or you use `window.onload` event, like so:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hi";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add quotes to the string you want to insert:

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hi";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title> Test </title>
      <script src="01_using_javascript.js"> </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p id="demo"></p>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the line in 01_using_javascript.js to `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hi";`.  The browser does not recognise Hi on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

use  here word "defer" plays a major role of downloading and running the script,

Problem Reason:"In your code the script loads before the dom content is loaded and `document.getElementById("demo")` finds nothing"